# Problem with system of differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $$F\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$$
$$u'(t)=F(u(t))$$
Let $w$ and $v$ two solutions defined in (a,b) of the equation above.

1)Proof that, if $dF(x)$ (the differential of F in x) satisfies
$$(dF(x)z,z)_2\leq 0 \qquad \forall x,z\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
then $$\phi(t)=||w(t)-v(t)||^2$$
is decreasing.

2)Let $s$ a solution defined for $t>0$. If
$$ (dF(x)z,z)_2\leq -||z||^2 \qquad\forall x,z\in \mathbb{R}^n$$
Proof that, if exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that
$$F(\lambda)=0$$
Then
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}s(t)=\lambda$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{split}
F(u(t))-F(v(t))
&=\int_0^1\frac{d}{dt}F(su(t)+(1-s)v(t))\,ds\\
&=\int_0^1 dF(su(t)+(1-s)v(t))(u(t)-v(t))\,ds\\
\end{split}
$$
and so
$$
\phi'(t)=2(F(u(t))-F(v(t)),u(t)-v(t))\le0.
$$
In the second part you can proceed in a similar manner starting with $\phi(t)=\|s(t)-\lambda\|^2$ for which one can get
$$
\phi'(t)=2(F(s(t))-\lambda,s(t)-\lambda)\le-\int_0^1\phi(r)\,dr.
$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see how you connected $\color{red}{a}$ with $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{d}{dt} F(su(t)+(1-s)v(t))ds$

Comment: There is no relation to $a$, that was something appearing in your approach. Instead my answer gives a proof without using $a$.